# Boostrap and Angular: Keeping two tabs active at same time.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to categorize my content using two tabs menu, when clicking on any option on both menus the contents on the page are organized using the parameters as a basis for angular filters. 
The filters are working fine, the content is showing up perfectly but every time any option is selected after selecting the first one. The previous selected option in the menu becomes inactive.

In short. I want to see two active tabs at same time, each from both menus.

**Markup**

```
<body  ng-controller="exploreController as exploreCtrl">    
<div class="col-sm-3 sidenav"> <!--Tab Menu 1-->
<h4>Categories</h4>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li ng-class="{active:exploreCtrl.isSelected(0)}"><a ng-click="exploreCtrl.select(0)">New Entries</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:exploreCtrl.isSelected(4)}"><a ng-click="exploreCtrl.select(4)">Art</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active:exploreCtrl.isSelected(5)}"><a ng-click="exploreCtrl.select(5)">Comics</a></li>
</ul>        
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="Tabs"> <!--Tab Menu 2-->
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:exploreCtrl.isSelected(1)}" >
    <a role="tab" ng-click="exploreCtrl.select(1)">Projects</a></li>

    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:exploreCtrl.isSelected(2)}" >
    <a role="tab" ng-click="exploreCtrl.select(2)">Teams</a></li>

    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:exploreCtrl.isSelected(3)}" >
    <a role="tab" ng-click="exploreCtrl.select(3)">Professionals</a></li></ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">
        <li ng-repeat = "proteam in exploreCtrl.proteams | filter:exploreCtrl.filtText | filter:exploreCtrl.filtText1">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="media-left media-middle">
    <!--Content-->     
    </ul>
    </div></div></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('exploresModule',[]);
app.controller('exploreController',function() {

this.tab=1;

var proteams = [
    { //content },
this.proteams = proteams;
this.filtText = '';
this.filtText = '';
this.select = function(setTab) {
    this.tab = setTab;

    if (setTab === 0) { this.filtText = "newentry"; return}
    if (setTab === 1) { this.filtText = 'project';  return }
    if (setTab === 2) { this.filtText = 'team'; return }
};

this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
   return this.tab === checkTab;
}
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to have the `div`'s inside the `ul`?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap UI? Could you put your code into a JSFiddle or Plunkr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the same variable to keep track of both. One variable can only have one value so you can't easily keep track of two things.

What you probably just need to use one variable for the vertical set of tabs and one for the horizontal set of tabs.

Create a `select2()` and `isSelected2()` methods and use another variable for those methods, instead of sharing the `tab` variable they would use the `tab2` variable.

Here is a JS Fiddle that show the working solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/xx85s37t/